# Testimonial page content refusing to be centralized and its background image enlarges when margin is added to content

Tags: html, css, image, responsive, center

The content of the testimonial page keeps acting funny each time I try to centralise it on the page. I have tried setting the margin of the .content to 25% auto; but each time I try to tweak the background image becomes so large and still does not centralise.
I also have this bug on my home page where the background image shrinks and shows some white space cant seem to figure the problem

```
THE HTML CODE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta property="og:title" name="" content="">
  <meta property="og:url" name="" content="">
  <meta property="og:image" name="" content="">
  <meta property="og:type" name="" content="">
  <meta property="og:keywords" name="" content="">
  <meta property="og:description" name="description"
    content="No 1,Hospitality management and luxury company in New York USA.We offer our expertise with love in Event Planning and Production, Restaurant sales and consulting and Memorial and Funeral Services.">
  <title>Hill and Boyd - Home Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;1,200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="" href="logos/favicon2.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/event.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/restaurant.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/memorial.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/venue.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/portfolio.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- HOME PAGE CONTENT-->
  <div class="hb-page">
    <section id="navigation">
      <header>
        <div class="mobile">
          <a class="js-nav.toggle hb-nav-toggle" onclick="open">
            <div class="bun01"></div>
            <div class="patty"></div>
            <div class="bun02"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="navbar whitebg" id="navbar">
        <aside id="hb-aside">
          <nav id="menu" class="centertext fontlight">
            <ul>
              <img class="logo" src="logos/mainLogo.png" alt="">
              <li><a class="blacktxt" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
              <li><a class="blacktxt" href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
              <li><a class="blacktxt" href="html/about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
              <li><a class="blacktxt" href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
              <li><a class="blacktxt" href="html/portfolio.html">OUR PORTFOLIO</a></li>
              <li><a class="blacktxt" href="html/venue.html">EXCLUSIVE VENUES</a></li>
              <li><a class="blacktxt" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="navbarFooter blacktxt fontlight">
              <div class="divider"></div>

              <div class="navFContent">
                <p>
                  +1 (646) 580-7740
                </p>
                <p>
                  info@hillandboyd.com
                </p>
                <p>
                  New York, USA.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </aside>

      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="home-page">
      <div id="main">
        <aside id="home-page" class="">
          <div class="slideshow-container">

            <div class="home-page-slides">
              <img class="" src="Images/eventbg1.jpg" style="width:100%">
              <div class="desc-container">
                <div class="desc p30 whitebg">
                  <h6 class="goldtxt">Luxury Events</h6>
                  <h2 class="blacktxt">WE CREATE BEAUTIFUL EVENTS</h2>
                  <p class="greytxt fontlight">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt omnis quod iste temporibus suscipit nostrum asperiores voluptatem. Provident maiores qui officia tempore, eos veritatis, obcaecati!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="home-page-slides">
              <img class="" src="Images/restaurantbg1.jpg" style="width:100%">
              <div class="desc-container">
                <div class="desc p30 whitebg">
                  <h6 class="goldtxt ">Creating Impact</h6>
                  <h2 class="blacktxt"> WE PROVIDE STRATEGY TO BOOST SALES</h2>
                  <p class="greytxt fontlight">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi minima, cumque dicta, minus, sit, praesentium officia deleniti beatae necessitatibus sequi tempora totam ut impedit dolores.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="home-page-slides">
              <img class="" src="Images/memorialbg1.jpg" style="width:100%">
              <div class="desc-container">
                <div class="desc p30 whitebg">
                  <h6 class="goldtxt ">Lasting Memories</h6>
                  <h2 class="blacktxt ">WE SERVE YOU WITH LOVE</h2>
                  <p class="greytxt fontlight">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum nam sequi dolorum similique praesentium, necessitatibus, aspernatur expedita sed natus illum ut, vitae! Possimus, tempore, facere!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </section>


<section id="testimonials">
      <div class="testimonials">
        <a name="testimonials"></a>
        <h6 class="goldtxt whitebg">what people are saying...</h6>
        <h1 class="blacktxt fontlight whitebg">TESTIMONIALS</h1>
        <div class=“testimonial-slider">
          <div class="testimonial-slide current">
            <div class="content">
              <h1>Antonio & Anica </h1>
              <p class="greytxt fontlight">
                "Antonio and I could never repay you for your contribution to our wedding.As you know,for most women,it is one of the most momentous occasions in their lifetime and that was certainly the case for me.<br />From the beginning,you
                knew how important that day would be for me and you added such unique elements of class and style.<br />You truly made our experience much better than what I had imagined it would be."
              </p>
          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="testimonial-slide">
            <div class="content">
              <h1>Mrs Beasley </h1>
              <p class="greytxt fontlight">
                "Dina is the best! The restaurant and dining room are chic and modern.
                The staff and owner are incredibly professional and warm.<br /> <br />
                Dina really helped us make our wedding reception and cocktail hour uniquely ours."
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="testimonial-slide">
            <div class="content">
              <h1>Bride Review</h1>
              <p class="greytxt fontlight">
                “ I feel incredibly honored to have worked with Dina! When my husband and I reflect on our wedding day,
                our biggest regret is not having met Dina sooner.<br /> <br />
                We can't wait to start planning a vow renewal celebration,
                so that we can have her plan the entire thing!!!"<br />
              </p>
             </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button id="prev"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
            <button id="next"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
          </div>

        </div>
    </section>


THE CSS CODE 
h1 {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 17px;
}

h6 {
  font-family: 'TuesdayNight';
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media screen and (min-device-width : 250px) and (max-width: 850px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  h6 {
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
}

/*----------------------------------------------------
@Home Page
-----------------------------------------------------*/
.slideshow-container, .main {
  width: calc(100%-300px);
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.desc-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 315px;
}

.desc {
  margin: auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.home-page-slides {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.home-page-slides img {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media screen and (min-device-width : 280px) and (max-width: 850px) {
  html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .desc-container {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10%;
    margin-bottom: -5%;
  }

  .desc {
    width: 75%;
    height: 25%;
    position: relative;
  }

  .home-page-slides img {
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------
@Testimonial Page
-----------------------------------------------------*/
.testimonials {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image: url(../Images/eventbg7.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

 .testimonial-slider {
  width:100%;
}

.testimonial-slide {
  width:calc(100%-300px);
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.testimonial-slide.current {
  opacity: 1;
}

.testimonial-slide .content {
  width:calc(100%-300px);
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  color: #333;
  padding: 35px;
}

.testimonial-slide .content{
opacity: 1;
}

.testimonial-slide .content h1 {

}

.testimonial-slide .content {
  opacity: 1;
  /* transform: translateX(600px);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0.3s; */
}

.buttons button#next {


}

.buttons button#prev {

}

.buttons button {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
}

.buttons button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Your link is dead?

Comment: it works, Just edited. so sorry